# Zend exception for default layout

Tags: zend-framework

I am using zend framework for my application
I have created all controllers and phtml files. Now I need to keep a login page. 
How can I create a login page without displaying the default.phtml contents.

sombody please help me..

Comment: Create a new layout called login, then apply the Tim Fountain's solution

Answer (score 2):

Rather than disabling the layout you probably want to get the login action to use a different layout instead. In your controller:

```
$this->getHelper('layout')->setLayout('login');
```